# Recombine separated complex variables back into single variable

Tags: formatting, complex

I have variables in an expression that have been previously expanded into their real and imaginary parts, that I later wish to recombine to a single variable. For example, a function or operation that would be able to convert  $\sqrt{2} \,\textrm{Re}(a) - i \sqrt{2} \,\textrm{Im}(a)$ back to $\sqrt{2} \,a^*$, etc.

Is there a function I am missing that already does this? `FullSimplify` does achieve this, but also converts the $\sqrt{2}$ into a decimal and takes a lot of time for longer expressions, which is not ideal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be pretty fast:

```
replaceReIm = {Re[x_] :> (x + Conjugate[x])/2, 
   Im[x_] :> (x - Conjugate[x])/(2 I)};

Simplify[Sqrt[2] Re[a] - I Sqrt[2] Im[a] /. replaceReIm]

(* ==> Sqrt[2] Conjugate[a] *)
```

Answer (score 3):

`ComplexExpand` is good for the rewriting part and following up with `Expand` combines like terms. For `ComplexExpand` one needs to specify that the variable is explicitly complex-valued, and also one needs to give desired "target" functions.

```
Expand[
 ComplexExpand[Sqrt[2] Re[a] - I Sqrt[2] Im[a], {a}, 
  TargetFunctions -> {Conjugate}]]

(* Out[831]= Sqrt[2] Conjugate[a] *)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works:

```
Sqrt[2] Re[a] - I Sqrt[2] Im[a] // FullSimplify
```

This yields:

```
Sqrt[2] Conjugate[a]
```

Comment: Correct, `FullSimplify` does work, but as mentioned above, is not ideal. The expression I am applying `FullSimplify` to is quite complicated and large, and `FullSimplify` tries to do much more than just look for much more than is required, causing it to have a very long runtime. 

Also, when I execute the above operation, I do not receive `Sqrt[2] Conjugate[a]` but `1.41421 Conjugate[a]`, which is not ideal.

Comment: Then, I guess, there must be some other reason why it converts this to a numeric expression. For example, if you type 2. instead of 2, it treats the expression numerically.